# Laravel Model factories belongsTo relationship not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, factories

everyone i have a question regarding Laravel **Model Factories**, i have the following factory definition.

```
$factory->define(Video::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        "title"         => $faker->unique()->text,
        "description"   => $faker->text(),
        "created_at"    => $faker->dateTimeThisYear
    ];
});
```

Basically this model has two `belongsTo` relationships with the *contents* and *resources* tables, and defines as such a *content_id* and a *resource_id* column.

So i expect this seeder to create the content, the resource and then attach them to the Video model before creating it.

```
    factory(Video::class, 50)->create()->each(function($item) {
        /** @var $item Video */
        $item->content()->associate(factory(Content::class)->create());
        $item->resource()->associate(factory(Resource::class)->create());
    });
```

However this does not work, and i get an error about the content_id foreign key on the `videos` table. What am i doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way: **Create factories for the models and reference them from the new factory**

```
$factory->define('App\Content', function(Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'body' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});

$factory->define('App\Resource', function(Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [

    ];
});

$factory->define('App\Video', function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        "title"         => $faker->unique()->text,
        "content_id" => function() {
            return factory('App\Content')->create()->id;
        },
        "resource_id" => function() {
            return factory('App\Resource')->create()->id;
        },
        "description"   => $faker->text(),
        "created_at"    => $faker->dateTimeThisYear
    ];
});
```

I am assuming your Video class is namespaced under App. You can remove the App namespacce if your classes are not namespaced..

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign the respective content and resource id  `factory('App\Content')->create()`, and `laravel` automatically assigns the appropriate id for you.
Example:

```
"resource_id" => factory('App\Content')->create(),
```